# Install IIS Media Services on Azure Web Role Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I want to install IIS Media Services on Azure Web Role Virtual Machine instance.

For more detail see : http://azlivestreaming.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home

One way to do is http://azlivestreaming.codeplex.com/discussions/257666, but not explained well.

**IIS Media Services 4**

IIS Media Services 4 is automatically installed and configured via Web role startup tasks and Web Administration API.

Comment: And why don't you take a look at [Windows Azure Media Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/media/) before you try inventing the wheel? All the references you provide are rather rather old and way before the Media Services where on the Azure list of Services. Unless you want LIVE STREAMING today, and you fully and deeply understand IIS Media Services, I suggest that you pay good attention to the Windows Azure Media Services.

Comment: I'm already using Windows Azure Media Service for on demand shows. But for now it is not supporting live streaming, if it supports then this will the best solution of my problem. Due to this reason I'm using [VM's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156003.aspx) with IIS Media Services installed. Limitations/problems with azure vm and they are:
1. If vm restart, no data will be accessible via publish point.
2. No way to set Archive path to azure blob storage.
If you know any link, doc for azure media service live streaming, please share with me. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the details from the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In either way, I suggest that you give up the links provided, as they are very outdated and have the issues you mention. Rather then going for the PaaS solution, check the IaaS solution.

To address the first issue, you shall check out the [Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-machines/). This is IaaS (Infrastructure-as-a-Services) offering from Microsoft. You have a persistent VM with guaranteed no data loss if hardware failure occurs. I'm not entirely sure how IIS Media Services work with the publish points, but while a WebRole (PaaS offering) is a stateless non-persistent VM, the Windows Azure Virtual Machine is state full VM. So whatever you can do in your local mini(or mega) data center with virtualized servers, you (most probably) can do with Windows Azure VM.

You can address issue two (archive path to Azure Blob) indirectly. Directly it is not possible. But indirectly, using a IaaS VM you can [attach additional data disk](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/). Depending on the VM size you have different quota on the number of data disks attached. Each data disk can be up to 999GB in size. A Data Disk is persisted as Page Blob in Windows Azure Blob Storage. So it is as redundant (3 copies) and reliable as the Blob Storage itself. Now you can point the archive path to be a volume (or NTFS path) that represents this data disk. Downside is that only one VM can read **and** write to the same disk (VHD file in Blob Storage) at a time. Also, you will not be able to directly access the archives in the blob storage, as you would normally do. But the end goal is to have the archive reliably and redundantly stored, right?

Comment: Thanks Anton,

I am having an Windows azure virtual machine with IIS Media Services installed on it. VM properties are : **Size : Small **, **Location : West US**
I have attached an VHD from my "West US" storage to store the media assets. Finally I understand that we can not set the blob storage path to archive path as it needs the [UNC](http://www.uwplatt.edu/oit/terms/uncpath.html) path.

Comment: My current scenario is the same as you suggested. But I faced a situation that, if VM restart then the connection between publish point and archive folder is lost and we can not set it back manually or by code.

It scares me that i'll have many live and on-demand videos.

Also there are Data Disk Limit (2 disks of almost 1TB in small).

Well for now, I think, I have to go with this.

-------Thanks for your valuable comments and answer.

Comment: I wonder why is this limitation with the publish point after restart. Does it also occur on a non-virtualized installation? If it does - then this is how IIS Media Services is running and we can do nothing. But if it doesn't - it is interesting issue to explore a bit deeper. As for On-Demand videos I suggest that you fully use the Media Services.

Comment: It happens on all machines, not only on Virtual machines. I test it with my own machine and my test server both. This is the way IIS Media Services is running and **you are right** we can not do anything. For your more information, also we can not set the complete archive path. I mean if we set **"c:\Archive\"** to the archive path then IIS will create the complete archive path like : **"C:\Archive\<IIS Site>\<Website>\<Publishpoint Name>\<DateTime>\Segment001........"**

Comment: I see. but at least you can mount a (single or more than one in a strip) VHD under `c:\archive`, or whatever. To at least have a dedicated archive storage. You can use 2x1TB VHDs and STRIP them to have single 2TB drive in Windows.

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks
Can you please give me some links to STRIP VHDs.
And by **you can mount a (single or more than one in a strip) VHD under c:\archive** did you mean add new VHD as a drive and use it (as we do to add VHD) OR something else? To be honest, I'm confuded with the words **under c:\archive**.

Comment: `under c:\archive` I meant that you can not just mount your VHD as a logical drive (i.e. D:, E:, F: etc.) but as a folder within the system logical drive. Check this out: [NTFS Mount Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_volume_mount_point)

Comment: And sorry, it is **STRIPE**, not **STRIP** - check [this article](http://tk.azurewebsites.net/2012/06/18/windows-azure-iaas-performance-sql-and-iops/). Although the article shows 12 disks in stripe, the suggested optimal performance is to use 4 disks in a stripe.